# How is the pricing setup for Azure DocumentDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Recently, [Azure DocumentDB](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/documentdb/) came out of preview and is available in General.
I wanted to know how the pricing is set if I have a **DB with Two separate collections** in it? Currently, the Pricing Calculator doesn't show Document DB in it.

Say S1 pricing is $25/month and I have one database with two collections on S1.

So will I be charged:

a) $25, since I have one database

b) $50, since I have two collections

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about pricing, not programming. See [Are questions on prices or support of developer services on topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274576/are-questions-on-prices-or-support-of-developer-services-on-topic) and [Why we're not customer support for...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: This pay per Collection is discouraging me to use DocumentDB. I hope them update this billing method and bill per database/diskusage/requests, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a hard time getting information on how the [DocumentDB pricing](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/documentdb/) works. After lots of emails and support requests, I found that the pricing is based on per collection basis.

So, if I have a DB with say two collections in it and each with a performance tier of S1 i.e., $25/month.

Then, I will be charged

> $25 x 2 = $50

In case, you go higher on the performance, say one of the collection was set for S2 and one remained in S1 then the pricing will go as

> $50 + $25 = $75

Also, note that you will be billed the flat rate for each hour the unit exists, regardless of usage or if the unit is active for less than an hour.

*For example, if you create a unit and delete it 5 minutes later, your bill will reflect a charge for 1 unit hour.*

For more FAQ on DocumentDB, you can check the FAQ section in this [link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/documentdb/).

Comment: Also note that you can alter a collection's tier at any time, which will change the per-hour rate accordingly. This is helpful if, for example, you have burst-traffic during a certain period of the day, where you need more database throughput. You can scale up during this time, then scale back during "quiet time."

Comment: It should also be noted, that as of the time of writing, a DocumentDB Account that does not contain any Collections, is still charged at an S1 price level (typically $25 / month). In order to halt all charges, you need to delete the DocumentDB Account too.  
"A database account that contains no databases or collections incurs a cost equivalent to an S1 collection per hour. To avoid this charge the database account itself, not just the databases within that account, must be deleted."
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/documentdb/